# Jupyter notebooks and scripts in the same package?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter (and or JupyterLab) to develop and auto- `nbconvert` to python script with with `post_save_hook`.

Currently both .ipynb and .py files are in the package.

Is it a good idea to have both the these in the same package or what's a good approach to organizing these? First of all it looks cluttered to have .ipynb and .py together.

Should these be separated in `Notebooks` and `Scripts` subfolders (and add **init**.py) in the latter?

I'm aware of `nbconvert` `--output-dir='path'` option but am not currently using it.

Comment: I recommend you to organize as you want as long you are coherent during all the project development. I usually keep them separate but there's no exist any standard on how to organize py and ipynb

Comment: @Guillem, (1) do you auto-`nbconvert` notebooks to the package folder (if so using `output-dir` switch?  (2) Are your notebooks also in the package folder or not included there?

Comment: I am not used to nbconvert, sorry man

Comment: You may also wish to use Jupytext's paired notebooks, see [here](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#paired-notebooks).